# mfc - Many frames open at once

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a C++ mfc application where I am trying to open many documents at once using CMultiDocTemplate. 
I find that the application crashes as soon as I call InitialUpdateFrame for the 157th document.
Can anyone please tell me where this limitation lies?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the crash? Are you running it in the IDE when it crashes, can you catch an exception or get an error result from your app?

Comment: Please provide crash call stack

Comment: I cant seem to find any other information. I'm running the .exe directly on my PC. I know it crashes when i call the InitialUpdateFrame function of the CMultiDocTemplate class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probable reason - you reached Windows USER or GDI objects limit. By default process cannot create more than 10000 USER and 10000 GDI objects. If your document view contains a lot of controls/graphical objects it's very easy to exceed the limit. 10000 / 157 = 63.

So if your document view creates 63 or more [USER objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (windows, icons, cursors etc) or [GDI objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (bitmaps, pens, brushes, fonts etc) MFC will throw [`CResourceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx1ef6z1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) exception and if you don't handle it explicitly application will abort due to unhandled exception.

It's very easy to check if this is real root cause of your problem. Open Task Manager, select `Processes` tab, in menu `View->Select columns...` check `USER Objects` and `GDI Objects`. Run your application and see objects count consumed by your app process.

See this excellent article for details: [Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/02/24/3315174.aspx).

Comment: This is the problem. I never knew of that means of seeing the number of GDI Objects used. Thanks a lot!